# Проверка на наличие слов в повелительном наклонении

Tags: python, python-3.x, проверка, анализ, nlp

И так, у меня есть переменная poisk, к которой мы будем обращаться.
Допустим пользователь ввел в нее такую строку: "Позвони контакту Х".
И если эта строчка содержит слово в повелительном наклонении (как у нас в примере "позвони"), то выполнялся бы определенный код.
Если же нет - другой.

Но так получилось, что русский язык невероятно огромный и я просто не смогу перечислить все эти слова

Есть какие нибудь идеи?

Вот, что я пытался сделать..

```
if poisk.find('найди' or 'позвони' ......) != -1:

    print("Smth")

else:

    print("Smth")
```

Comment: Язык огромный, но количество действий, которые вы можете реализовать - ограничен. Если это грубо говоря 5 разных действий, то не стоит особо и заморачиваться, достаточно обычного if.

Comment: ну тут явно надо проверять наклонение слова, а как вы это кодом реализуете?)

Comment: прочитайте про библиотеку `re` (сиречь Regular Expressions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/0.2/user/index.html).

Пример:

```
import nltk         #  pip install nltk
import pymorphy2    #  pip install pymorphy2 pymorphy2-dicts

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

def get_imperative(word):
    for p in morph.parse(word):
        if p.tag.mood and p.tag.mood == 'impr':
            return p.normal_form
    return None
```

Использование:

```
In [31]: [get_imperative(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize("Позвони контакту Х")]
Out[31]: ['позвонить', None, None]

In [32]: [get_imperative(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize("позвоните пожалуйста контакту Х")]
Out[32]: ['позвонить', None, None, None]

In [33]: [get_imperative(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize("Кышь отсюда!")]
Out[33]: ['кышать', None, None]

In [34]: [get_imperative(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize("напомни мне как тебя зовут!")]
Out[34]: ['напомнить', None, None, None, None, None]

In [35]: [get_imperative(word) for word in nltk.word_tokenize("напомните мне пожалуйста как вас зовут!")]
Out[35]: ['напомнить', None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

PS дальше, я думаю, справитесь сами)

Comment: nltk только для разбиения на слова - это немного из пушки по воробью. Но в целом плюсую.

Comment: @insolor, согласен, но обычно если используется `pymorphy2` то наверняка найдется применение и `nltk`